# Having issues with filtering foreign key through postgrest cURL get request

Tags: postgrest

I've recently hit a brick wall when filtering foreign key through postgrest api, I've been going through the documentation and I can't seem to find a way, the query returns filtered array in addition to results that I don't need, but with a nulled fields. Is there a way to filter null fields too or clean up my api request?
My example look like this:

**Table 1 - Orders**

SKU
owner_foreign_key(FK) - this is the foreign key I'm using

**Table 2 - Vehicles**
SKU
owner_name [array] - this is the array I'm looking to filter my query by, provided cURL example

/rest/v1/orders?owner_foreign_key.owner_name=eq.{owner_name}&select=SKU,owner_foreign_key(owner_name)

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by calling !inner before foreign key field. As shown in the documentation. /facepalm